# Unbelievably low accuracy on the validation set by Keras-Python on the mnist dataset

Tags: python-3.x, validation, keras, mnist

I am puzzled with the performance of my keras model on the validation set with the mnist data.

I am using the test data only for short which I download as a csv file from here: https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/

My code is the following:

```
mnist = pd.read_csv('mnist_test.csv', header = None)
mnist.head()
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     775     776     777     778     779     780     781     782     783     784
0   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

X = mnist.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = to_categorical(mnist.iloc[:, 0])

n_cols = X.shape[1]

# Create the model: model
model = Sequential()

# Add the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784,)))

# Add the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))

# Add the output layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, y, validation_split = 0.3)
```

The output is:

```
Train on 7000 samples, validate on 3000 samples

Epoch 1/1
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 109us/step - loss: 10.9961 - acc: 0.3111 - val_loss: 10.2264 - val_acc: 0.3637
```

Accuracy of 0.36 in the validation set?  Is unbelievable.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the number of neurons per layer?

Comment: And number of epochs? Find some of the online tutorials for mnist and see how they do it. In a lot of them they explain what they have tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add normalization to your code. Then it should work fine

```
X =  X.astype('float32')
y =  y.astype('float32')

X /= 255
```

i.e.

```
X = mnist_test.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = to_categorical(mnist_test.iloc[:, 0])

X =  X.astype('float32')
y =  y.astype('float32')

X /= 255

n_cols = X.shape[1]

# Create the model: model
model = Sequential()

# Add the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784,)))

# Add the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))

# Add the output layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, y, validation_split = 0.3, epochs=10)
```

Tested, giving me:

```
Train on 7000 samples, validate on 3000 samples
Epoch 1/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 179us/step - loss: 0.7758 - acc: 0.7734 - val_loss: 0.3359 - val_acc: 0.9073
Epoch 2/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 137us/step - loss: 0.3104 - acc: 0.9056 - val_loss: 0.2225 - val_acc: 0.9330
Epoch 3/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 133us/step - loss: 0.2291 - acc: 0.9339 - val_loss: 0.1958 - val_acc: 0.9390
Epoch 4/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 138us/step - loss: 0.1845 - acc: 0.9461 - val_loss: 0.1827 - val_acc: 0.9433
Epoch 5/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 138us/step - loss: 0.1509 - acc: 0.9571 - val_loss: 0.1678 - val_acc: 0.9483
Epoch 6/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 143us/step - loss: 0.1240 - acc: 0.9641 - val_loss: 0.1760 - val_acc: 0.9407
Epoch 7/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 136us/step - loss: 0.1012 - acc: 0.9710 - val_loss: 0.1801 - val_acc: 0.9453
Epoch 8/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 138us/step - loss: 0.0838 - acc: 0.9761 - val_loss: 0.1867 - val_acc: 0.9457
Epoch 9/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 132us/step - loss: 0.0697 - acc: 0.9780 - val_loss: 0.1820 - val_acc: 0.9450
Epoch 10/10
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 135us/step - loss: 0.0559 - acc: 0.9843 - val_loss: 0.1699 - val_acc: 0.9493
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do more epochs for training.

therefor insert "epochs=200" in the model.fit command.